Define strings representing macros in lualatex
I am using trying to define a variable in LuaLaTeX which holds a string representing a macro. The idea is (eventually) to pass that string to a tex.print and have the macro called. For example:
\directlua{
T="\\top"
}

But when I try and compile the above code I get the error
Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e \relax \let \reserved@f 
                                               \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...

I am unsure even what the issue is with this code, much less what I should do to make it work.

you are expanding \\  before passing it to Lua, use \string\\top

David's comment will solve the example you posted, but as a rule of thumb,  directlua should be enclosed in the definition of a macro and not the other way around. I will explain the reasons in my answer below.

Do also take a look at the posting How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX and its accepted answer [shameless self-citation alert!]. The upshot is that without incurring too much overhead, you can set up natural-looking (and -feeling) ways to set up macros of the type you say you wish to create.

David's comment solves the issue posted by the OP. However, more will appear down the line as the code grows. Many problems arise if the code is not structured properly. As a rule of thumb, the Lua code should be enclosed in the definition of a macro and not the other way around it. This also permits running the Lua code in IDE and testing it on its own without the complications of TeX processing. It also avoids most common issues with catcodes and expansion.
You can also include on top of the Lua code:
if type(tex)=="table" then print = tex.print end

This will print both in the console and in the document correctly. Well structured code, inevitably leads to a mymodule.sty file and a mymodule.lua file.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
\def\mytop{something}
\NewDocumentCommand\powers{ m m }{%
\directlua{
  local x, n = #1, #2 
  local s1 = "\\begin{gather}"
  local s2 = "\\end{gather}"
  local result = x^n
  tex.print(s1.. x .. "^{" .. n .. "}=" .. result .. s2)
  tex.print("\\mytop")
  }
}
\begin{document}
\powers{10}{2.99999999999999}
\powers{2}{2.99999999999999}
\end{document}

Implementing the suggestions to split the code to a Lua module and a LaTeX package, we have:
\documentclass{article}
% The Lua module code
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{powers.lua}
 -- powers calculator and pretty printer!
 if type(table)=="table" then print = tex.print end
 function powers(x,n) 
  local s1 = "\\begin{gather}"
  local s2 = "\\end{gather}"
  local result = x^n
  print(s1.. x .. "^{" .. n .. "}=" .. result .. s2)
  print("\\mytop")
end
\end{filecontents*}
% The package code
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{powers.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{powers}[2024/06/30 Calculates and prints powers]
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\def\mytop{say something}
\NewDocumentCommand\powers{ m m }{%
\directlua{
  require("powers")
  powers(#1,#2)
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{powers}
\begin{document}
\powers{10}{2.99999999999999}
\powers{2}{2.99999999999999}
\end{document}


